# Using df.loc, I want to see if a column is numeric, how do I do that?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DF:

```
Color   Name    Age   City   Value
Blue    Bob     28    Atl    0
Green   Bob     27    Chi    -
Blue    Sam     28    Atl    0
```

I want to change the age of all columns that have the color blue, and a numeric Value to 30.  In df.loc I am not sure how to specific that I want value to be numeric.  How do I do that?

Comment: Can you explain `I am not sure how to specific that I want value to be numeric` ?

Comment: Hey, I actually just figured it out.  It was pretty simple.  I just did:  df.Age!=np.nan

Comment: Not `df.Age.notnull()` ?

Comment: When I try that I get: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'nonnull'

Comment: I think `notnull()`

Comment: TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [bool] array with a scalar of type [bool]

Comment: What is your full code?

Comment: I am importing data from an excel sheet.  Then I do: df = df.replace('-', np.nan).  That might be why that is caused.

Comment: And then? `df.replace('-', np.nan)` looks nice

Comment: df.loc[(df.color=='Blue')&(df.Age!=np.nan),'value']='Changed'

Comment: ^ I do something like that afterwards.  It may be the data I have in the excel sheet.

Comment: Sorry, need Need `df.loc[(df.color=='Blue')&(df.Age.notnull()),'value']='Changed'`

Comment: It worked.  I had to restart kernel in jupyter notebook....